# Take a picture on a specific tablet crashes the application

Tags: android

I am facing a new problem that happens only on a Chinese tablet that I am using for test my applications. This problem doesn't exist in other tablets. 
I just take a picture as usually. The line that causes the crash is the following: *camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegPictureCallBack);*

And the "jpegPictureCallBack" isn't called. The crash happens in native code, so I guess it's possible it is a firmware problem, but I am not sure. Any suggestions? Here there's the logcat trace:

```
09-03 16:28:10.659: E/CameraHardware(13422): CameraHardware::doTakePicture---------------->
09-03 16:28:10.739: D/PreviewWindow(13422): onNextFrameAvailable: Adjusting preview windows 0x41ac2a50 geometry to 640x480
09-03 16:28:10.739: E/CameraHardware(13422): CameraHardware::doTakePictureEnd---------------->
09-03 16:28:10.739: D/osal_linux(13422): use ion_alloc_open
09-03 16:28:10.739: D/osal_linux(13422): init hw ref count:1
09-03 16:28:10.739: D/PreviewWindow(13422): preview format: HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP
09-03 16:28:10.769: A/libc(13422): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x41b0a000 (code=2), thread 13426 (CameraPictrueTh)
09-03 16:28:10.819: I/DEBUG(130): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-03 16:28:10.819: I/DEBUG(130): Build fingerprint: 'Uarmtech/astar_uarmmid/astar-uarmmid:4.4.2/KVT49L/20150422:eng/test-keys'
09-03 16:28:10.819: I/DEBUG(130): Revision: '0'
09-03 16:28:10.819: I/DEBUG(130): pid: 13422, tid: 13426, name: CameraPictrueTh  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
09-03 16:28:10.819: I/DEBUG(130): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 41b0a000
09-03 16:28:10.829: W/NativeCrashListener(518): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 13422
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     r0 41b09ff0  r1 42734010  r2 000052ec  r3 00000008
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130): AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     r4 00012334  r5 4285da00  r6 41afd008  r7 4285da58
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     r8 00000016  r9 4142db2c  sl 00000000  fp 4285a5b0
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     ip 00000000  sp 4142d928  lr 4112f803  pc 4008e04c  cpsr 20070010
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d16 3ff1000000000000  d17 bfde000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d18 4004000000000000  d19 3fe0000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d20 4000000000000000  d21 3ff8000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 bfe1000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d24 bfe2100000000000  d25 3fa0000000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d26 4023d00000000000  d27 4024d00000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d28 406fb30000000000  d29 406fc30000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     d30 c01c200000000000  d31 c01a200000000000
09-03 16:28:10.959: I/DEBUG(130):     scr 60000010
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130): backtrace:
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #00  pc 0002204c  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+108)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #01  pc 000037ff  /system/lib/libjpgenc.so (JpegEnc+638)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #02  pc 0000b159  /system/lib/hw/camera.polaris.so (android::CallbackNotifier::takePicture(void const*, bool)+460)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #03  pc 000105f1  /system/lib/hw/camera.polaris.so (android::V4L2CameraDevice::pictureThread()+72)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #04  pc 0000e991  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+104)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #05  pc 0000e533  /system/lib/libutils.so
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #06  pc 0000d240  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):     #07  pc 0000d3dc  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130): stack:
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8e8  4434f000  anon_inode:dmabuf
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8ec  44351335  anon_inode:dmabuf
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8f0  00000005  
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8f4  4142d8e8  [stack:13426]
09-03 16:28:10.969: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8f8  42737008  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d8fc  4112da57  /system/lib/libjpgenc.so (JPGVENC_encode+1170)
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d900  40d81004  /system/lib/libcedarxbase.so
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d904  434d50d0  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d908  4285dae8  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d90c  4142d940  [stack:13426]
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d910  4285dae8  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d914  4142d940  [stack:13426]
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d918  41afd008  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d91c  4112d2c1  /system/lib/libjpgenc.so (JPGVENC_GetBsInfo+112)
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d920  4142d970  [stack:13426]
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d924  4142db40  [stack:13426]
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):     #00  4142d928  41afd008  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d92c  4112f803  /system/lib/libjpgenc.so (JpegEnc+642)
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):     #01  4142d930  00000014  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d934  400ba384  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d938  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d93c  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d940  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d944  42727008  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d948  00012334  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d94c  42727008  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d950  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d954  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d958  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d95c  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d960  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d964  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d968  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142d96c  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          ........  ........
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):     #02  4142db20  434d3710  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db24  00000001  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db28  00000011  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db2c  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db30  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db34  00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db38  00000280  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db3c  000001e0  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db40  00000280  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db44  000001e0  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db48  000000b0  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db4c  00000090  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db50  195f0000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db54  1963b000  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db58  00000005  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          4142db5c  0000005f  
09-03 16:28:10.979: I/DEBUG(130):          ........  ........
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r0:
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b09fd0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b09fe0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b09ff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a000 464c457f 00010101 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a010 00280003 00000001 00000000 00000034  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a020 00001150 05000000 00200034 00280008  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a030 00150016 00000006 00000034 00000034  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a040 00000034 00000100 00000100 00000004  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a050 00000004 00000003 00000134 00000134  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a060 00000134 00000013 00000013 00000004  
09-03 16:28:10.989: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a070 00000001 00000001 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a080 00000000 00000ce1 00000ce1 00000005  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a090 00001000 00000001 00000e68 00001e68  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a0a0 00001e68 0000019c 0000019c 00000006  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a0b0 00001000 00000002 00000eb0 00001eb0  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a0c0 00001eb0 00000108 00000108 00000006  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r1:
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42733ff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734070 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     42734090 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     427340a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     427340b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     427340c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     427340d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     427340e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r2:
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000052cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000052dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000052ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000052fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000530c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000531c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000532c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000533c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000534c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000535c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000536c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000537c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000538c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     0000539c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000053ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     000053bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r4:
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     00012314 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:10.999: I/DEBUG(130):     00012324 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012334 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012344 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012354 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012364 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012374 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012384 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012394 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123e4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     000123f4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     00012404 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r5:
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285d9e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285d9f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000006b  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da00 195f0000 1963b000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000016  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da20 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da30 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da40 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da50 00000000 00000000 434d50d0 4285a5b0  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da60 636f663b 00000081 400ba228 400ba228  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da70 006e0061 00720064 0069006f 002e0064  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da80 00750067 002e0069 00470049 00610072  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da90 00680070 00630069 00750042 00660066  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285daa0 00720065 00720050 0064006f 00630075  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dab0 00720065 00000000 00000001 00000029  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dac0 00000000 00000011 00000002 6c61746e  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dad0 6569762d 6e612d77 3d656c67 362e3435  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r6:
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afcfe8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afcff8 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000630b  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd008 e1ffd8ff 7845feff 00006669 002a4949  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd018 00000008 01120006 00010003 00010000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd028 01320000 00140002 00560000 010f0000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd038 00400002 006a0000 01100000 00400002  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd048 00aa0000 87690000 00010004 01f40000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd058 88250000 00010004 03f40000 07f40000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd068 30320000 303a3531 33303a39 3a363120  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd078 313a3832 414d0030 415f454b 00003333  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd088 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd098 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd0a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.009: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd0b8 00000000 4f4d0000 5f4c4544 00333341  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd0c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     41afd0d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r7:
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da38 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da48 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da58 434d50d0 4285a5b0 636f663b 00000081  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da68 400ba228 400ba228 006e0061 00720064  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da78 0069006f 002e0064 00750067 002e0069  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da88 00470049 00610072 00680070 00630069  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285da98 00750042 00660066 00720065 00720050  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285daa8 0064006f 00630075 00720065 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dab8 00000001 00000029 00000000 00000011  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dac8 00000002 6c61746e 6569762d 6e612d77  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dad8 3d656c67 362e3435 00000080 000010c2  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285dae8 00000006 00000050 00000040 00000140  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285daf8 000000f0 00000140 000000f0 00000050  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285db08 00000040 00000000 000f0014 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285db18 00000000 00000000 00000000 4434f000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285db28 1b800000 1bdfffff 00000000 00003380  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130): memory near r9:
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db0c 400ba384 00000000 3132564e 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db1c 410f215d 434d3710 00000001 00000011  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db2c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000280  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db3c 000001e0 00000280 000001e0 000000b0  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db4c 00000090 195f0000 1963b000 00000005  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db5c 0000005f 00000000 00000000 d70a3d71  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db6c 400b70a3 00000140 000000f0 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db7c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142db9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbbc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbcc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4142dbfc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130): memory near fp:
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a590 65786966 682d0064 00000048 00000032  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5a0 00000000 00000015 00000058 00000033  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5b0 4285dae8 41b165d0 4112d331 4112d2d5  
09-03 16:28:11.019: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5c0 4112d5c5 4112cfe1 4112d251 4112d215  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5d0 00000000 4112cfdd 00000030 0000004b  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5e0 00000001 434d5b70 41b05e78 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a5f0 00000050 00000010 00031408 00000001  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a600 434d5b80 4285af30 00000000 000002a0  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a610 00000020 00031f08 0e13110c 0c070a10  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a620 00000048 00000049 434d34c0 400ba1f0  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a630 00000000 00000000 006e0061 00720064  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a640 0069006f 002e0064 00610068 00640072  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a650 00610077 00650072 0049002e 00610043  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a660 0065006d 00610072 00000048 00000142  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a670 000b0001 00070002 00038032 803e0004  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4285a680 80420005 000d0006 00088033 80368034  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130): memory near sp:
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d908 4285dae8 4142d940 4285dae8 4142d940  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d918 41afd008 4112d2c1 4142d970 4142db40  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d928 41afd008 4112f803 00000014 400ba384  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d938 00000000 00000000 00000000 42727008  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d948 00012334 42727008 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d958 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d968 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000b0  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d978 00000090 00007530 00000016 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d988 00000028 00000014 00018c00 00000019  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d998 00000000 00000280 000001e0 00000003  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9a8 d70a3d71 400b70a3 0000005f 00000001  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4142d9f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130): code around pc:
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e02c f400071d e2522040 3a000006 f421020d  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e03c f421420d f5d1f100 e2522040 f400022d  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e04c f400422d 2afffff8 e2922020 3a000002  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e05c f421020d e2422020 f400022d e2822020  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e06c e3120010 0a000001 f4210a0d f4000a2d  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e07c e1b0ce82 3a000001 f421070d f400070d  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e08c aa000001 f4a1030d f480030d e1b02f82  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e09c 14d1e001 14c0e001 24d1c001 25d1e000  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0ac 24c0c001 25c0e000 e8bd8001 e0203001  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0bc e2133003 1affffc8 e16d40f8 e16d60f8  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0cc e16d80f8 e210c003 1a000042 e2103004  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0dc 0a000002 e4913004 e4803004 e2422004  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0ec e2422040 e1c140d0 e1c040f0 e1c140d8  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e0fc e1c040f8 e1c141d0 e1c041f0 e1c141d8  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e10c e1c041f8 e1c142d0 e1c042f0 e1c142d8  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4008e11c e1c163d0 e1c183d8 f5d1f400 e1c042f8  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130): code around lr:
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f7e0 22304651 f7fda804 6de8eb7e 6982a904  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f7f0 46824790 9c06bb08 46224630 f7fd9905  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f800 9f08eb60 99071930 f7fd463a 19e0eb5a  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f810 543121ff 183623d9 70731c84 4000f8c9  
09-03 16:28:11.029: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f820 99046de8 479069c2 b1306de8 478868c1  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f830 f7fe6de8 f8c5f9b7 f105a05c f7fd0058  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f840 b115eb9a f7fd4628 9b01eb24 68199a71  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f850 428a4650 f7fdd001 b073eb64 8ff0e8bd  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f860 000019f6 fffffff8 00000517 0000051f  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f870 000005c9 000004e9 00000503 000004c5  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f880 000004fd 00000562 00000385 000003d8  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f890 0000033b 000003a6 000002ed 0000036e  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f8a0 46c04778 e59fc000 e08cf00f ffffd598  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f8b0 7fffd72c 80b0b0b0 7fffd728 80aeb0b0  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f8c0 7fffd954 80aab0b0 7fffd988 80b108a9  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     4112f8d0 7fffdabc 80b107af 7fffdb30 80acb0b0  
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130): memory map around fault addr 41b0a000:
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     41afb000-41b0a000 rw- 
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0a000-41b0b000 r-x /system/lib/libstagefrighthw.so
09-03 16:28:11.039: I/DEBUG(130):     41b0b000-41b0c000 r-- /system/lib/libstagefrighthw.so
09-03 16:28:11.249: I/BootReceiver(518): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-03 16:28:11.269: W/AudioSystem(14072): AudioFlinger server died!
09-03 16:28:11.269: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(14072): media server died
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/AudioSystem(1306): AudioFlinger server died!
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/CameraBase(14072): Camera service died!
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(518): media server died
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/CameraBase(14072): mediaserver's remote binder Camera object died
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/AudioSystem(1306): AudioPolicyService server died!
09-03 16:28:11.279: E/Camera(14072): Error 100
09-03 16:28:11.279: W/AudioSystem(14072): AudioPolicyService server died!
09-03 16:28:11.279: I/ServiceManager(127): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
09-03 16:28:11.279: I/ServiceManager(127): service 'media.player' died
09-03 16:28:11.279: I/ServiceManager(127): service 'media.camera' died
09-03 16:28:11.279: I/ServiceManager(127): service 'media.audio_policy' died
09-03 16:28:11.359: W/AudioSystem(518): AudioFlinger server died!
09-03 16:28:11.359: E/AudioService(518): Media server died.
```

Comment: If you don't have any native code, it is almost assuredly a firmware bug.

Comment: It must be an OS bug, i work with some chinese devices and i have faced some similar issues, some features works great, but some others doesn't work at all.

Comment: I solved guys! I was setting a Picture Size that wasn't supported!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**     I was setting bad parameters for what concerns the picture size. This causes a fault in the native camera code.

Used this instead:

```
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setPreviewSize(..., ...); //use params.getPreviewSize()
params.setPictureSize(..., ...); //use params.getPictureSize() to know sizes..
```